# How to send plain text emails using AlternateView and retain line breaks

Tags: c#, email, mailmessage

I'm sending plain text emails using an AlternateView.  The code I'm using is similar to:

```
var msg = new MailMessage();
var body = $"Test sending\nA newline character\nIn a plaintext email";

msg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddr);
msg.To = new MailAddress(toAddr);
msg.Subject = "Test";
msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

AlternateView textView;
textView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, Text.Encoding.UTF8, Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

AlternateView htmlView;
htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, Text.Encoding.UTF8, Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

msg.AlternateViews.Add(textView);
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer);
client.Send(msg);
```

When I receive the email though, it comes through as:

*Test sending A newline character In a plaintext email*

When I look at the original message sent, I can see that the linebreaks are there, so the email client is just not displaying them.

If I set msg.Body and don't use an AlternateView, the linebreaks come across as expected.

What do I need to do in order to have an AlternateView sent as plaintext display the line breaks correctly?

Comment: I think it probably wont work as you expect... Because that is the normal behavior of text in the web... If you want to format your emails you need to use html instead of plain text.

Comment: But if I don't use alternate view, and just set msg.Body, the line breaks come across fine

Comment: Not sure that will depende also on the email client and how it decides to render the email.

Comment: Why do you need to create an `AlternativeView` when you don't have an alternative view? For the plain text emails, just set the `Body` property. Read the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body?view=net-5.0#remarks) section.

Answer (score 0):

Content of emails can be html  or plain text so try to use "<br>" or "\r\n" [here](https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/kb/creator/email/articles/how-can-i-insert-line-breaks-to-my-e-mail-message) is an example